# How to fix error Emulator error after build/run android aosp (just show a black screen)

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source

I tried to compile and test android aosp following these steps:

```
1. clone android aosp ([https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading][1] )
2. lunch 2
3. m -j8
4. emulator
```

After that, emulator just show a black image as follow:

[image]

I don't know if are missing step to build and run android aosp code.
there is one suggestion to fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: lunch? are you sure?

Comment: "lunch 2" means  "aosp_arm64-eng" ? You should show more information such as console log, logcat, etc.

Comment: @TuanPM  yes. Actually, I tried again with aosp_phone_x86 and works fine. I don't know why not works with aos_arm64-eng

Comment: @RuddaBeltrao Your PC is probably x86 architecture, not arm architecture. So you need to build with  x86 or x86_64.